# Upload file to firebase storage when internet is offline using swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

When internet is offline i can sync database using

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

Is it possible to do with firebase storage ?

If yes, how can I do it ?

If no, any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Storage doesn't offer a similar feature, though it's on our roadmap. There's some more info here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/147

You can use something like [GTMSessionFetcher](https://github.com/google/gtm-session-fetcher), which offers a [`useBackgroundSession`](https://github.com/google/gtm-session-fetcher/blob/master/Source/GTMSessionFetcher.h#L79-L115) flag, or the built-in [NSURLSessionConfiguration `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1407496-backgroundsessionconfigurationwi?language=objc)